# Need help on a problem on trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

[image]

In triangle ABC, AB=10, CA=12. The bisector of ∠ intersects CA at E, and the bisector of ∠
intersects AB at D. AM and AN are the perpendiculars to CD and BE respectively. If MN=4, then
find BC.

It isn't my homework, just a math problem that I randomly wanted to try out since I have no clue where to start with this.

Comment: I think the conditions are not enough. $MN=\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}$

Comment: @Oolongmilktea Could u plz tell me how u came to this?

Comment: Let $U,V$ denote the intersection of $AM,BC$ and $AN,BC$. $MN=\frac{UV}{2}=\frac{BV+CU-BC}{2}=\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}$.

Comment: why is MN= UV/2? Why  is the denominator 2 tho?

Comment: Notice $AM=MU AN=NV$.

Comment: Ohh, I get it, thank you so  much <3