# Triangle geometry with bisectors

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

In triangle $ABC$, $AB=10$, $CA=12$. The bisector of ∠**B** intersects $CA$ at $E$, and the bisector of ∠**C**
intersects $AB$ at $D$.

$AM$ and $AN$ are the perpendiculars to $CD$ and $BE$ respectively. If $MN=4$, then how can I find $BC$?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225582/its-about-geometry-about-triangle#) the question. [This post](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Whats your effort in this question. Did you tried it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221915/need-help-on-a-problem-on-trigonometry?rq=1

Comment: The [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).